# Using verbose in Laravel artisan commands

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, verbosity

Is there a way to detect what verbosity level the user has specified when creating a custom artisan command?  I don't see anything about it in the docs.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There's the `getVerbosity()` function in `Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface` and you can use `$this->getOutput()` to retrieve the output object.

```
$verbosityLevel = $this->getOutput()->getVerbosity();
```

You then can compare the level to the constants defined inside `OutputInterface`. For example:

```
if($verbosityLevel >= OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_VERBOSE){
    // show verbose messages
}
```

Comment: Nice!  I'll give this a spin.  I also found that $this->option('verbose') works for giving you a simple boolean.  (It does not cover -v vs -vvv, however)

Comment: Cool didn't know about `option('verbose')`

Comment: You could also use `$this->output->isVerbose()` [api.symfony.com/3.1/...](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Console/Output/OutputInterface.html#method_isVerbose). `isVerbose()` is `-v`,  `isVeryVerbose()` is `-vv`,  `isDebug()` is `-vvv`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just using `$isVerbose = $this->option("verbose");` which keeps it super simple (just check that one boolean variable wherever needed).

Answer (score 23):

You can use different verbosities as per the documentation:

https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Console/OutputStyle.html#method_isQuiet

```
isQuiet()       - no verbosity is set                                   (no option set)
isVerbose()     - if the level is quiet or verbose                      (-v)
isVeryVerbose() - if the level is very verbose, verbose or quiet        (-vv)
isDebug()       - if the level is debug, very verbose, verbose or quiet (-vvv)
```

e.g. In your command `$this->getOutput()->isQuiet()`

This also affects `writeLn()`. If you were to write `$this->line('Serious message', null, 'vv');` The message would appear for `-vv` and `-vvv` options, but not `-v` and silent modes as it is "too detailed" for those levels of logging.