# (Laravel 5.8) How to get verbosity level inside Exception Handler class

Tags: laravel, error-handling

I'm trying to get the verbosity level INSIDE the Exception Handler class so I can print more or less information.

I'm writing a batch script that runs over hundreds of thousands loops and so that my goal is to limit the verbosity of the stack trace, since in this case the only useful traces are the last 3 or 4.

I've tried some other answers given here in SO and have read all around Internet, but none of ther talk about working inside the exception handler.
The one that looks closer is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611513/697579) that states `$this->getOutput()->getVerbosity();`but that doesn't works inside the error handler.

This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

use Mail;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler as SymfonyExceptionHandler;
use App\Mail\ExceptionOccured;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler 
...
...
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        // return parent::render($request, $e);
        Log::error($this->buildMessage($e));
    }


    public function buildMessage($e) 
    {
        $verbosity_level = $this->getOutput()->getVerbosity();
        $is_verbose = ($verbosity_level >= OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_DEBUG);

        $t0 = $e->getTrace()[0];
        $tm = "Error: [{$e->getCode()}] {$e->getMessage()} @ {$t0['file']}:{$t0['line']}".PHP_EOL;
        // if ($is_verbose){
            ...(more code) ...
        // }
        return $tm;
    }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method App\Exceptions\Handler::getOutput() in ...\Handler.php:89
```

I've seen that the `output` property exists but it is protected and has no getter.
Maybe the cited answer is valid for earlier versions.
I'm really lost as I just have 2 months playing with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

The Exception handler has a specific method for the console: `renderForConsole()`.

```php
/**
 * Render an exception to the console.
 *
 * @param  \Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface  $output
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return void
 */
public function renderForConsole($output, Exception $e)
{
    (new ConsoleApplication)->renderException($e, $output);
}
```

It's a pretty simple wrapper around the Symfony Console component's default exception handler. Customize to your needs!