# Laravel schedule file deletion not working

Tags: php, laravel, macos, schedule

I've created a schedule method in the Kernel class:

```
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        $schedule->command('DataExport:RemoveTempFiles')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

and  the command looks like this:

```
class RemoveDataExportTempFiles extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'DataExport:RemoveTempFiles';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Removes temp files created during the DataExport process';

    public function handle(): int
    {
        Storage::disk('local')->deleteDirectory('data-export');

        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

I then run the schedule at the command line:

```
user@my-iMac csmwg % php artisan schedule:work

   INFO  Running scheduled tasks every minute.  

  2023-07-22 09:48:00 Running ['artisan' DataExport:RemoveTempFiles]
```

And it just hangs like that (as if it's crashed). The director and files inside are not deleted.

Note that I don't necessarily need to create a command. Any way of running this deletion on a schedule will be fine.

I also tried:

```
   $schedule->call(function () {
Storage::disk('local')->deleteDirectory('data-export');
    })->everyMinute();
```

but that resulted in:

```
user@my-iMac csmwg % php artisan schedule:work

   INFO  Running scheduled tasks every minute.  

  2023-07-22 08:24:00 Running [Callback] ........................... 30ms FAIL
```

Note that

```
Storage::disk('local')->deleteDirectory('data-export');
```

works fine if called within the code, so it has no problem finding the directory and deleting it in that case.

Can anyone help? Many thanks for your assistance.
Laravel 9.52.10, PHP 8.1.4, MacOs BigSur 11.7.6

EDIT

I've now discovered that if I run the same code on my Windows machine (Windows 10) it all works fine. So this is something to do with MacOs, or perhaps file system permissions.

Comment: I don't see any errors on this. Check the Schedule and permissions. Try Logging if fails

Comment: What happens when you run `'artisan' DataExport:RemoveTempFiles` on the command line? Have you tried running it more verbosely (`-vvv`, Cf.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27611213/367456)? Please [edit] your question and add any clarifications, basically what @AbdullaNilam commented, from the scenario presented, there is very little to say about. It might also help if you share your current understanding to get better feedback.

Comment: Do you assign `RemoveDataExportTempFiles` in protected?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've added some further information above.